# How filter top output by the COMMAND column?

Tags: ubuntu, performance, process, top

I want get the same result when pressing `u` to filter by **USER**, but instead using the column **COMMAND** and of course, I need this live (I mean, updating constantly) ;)

I'm on Ubuntu.

Comment: You don't mention which OS you are using; MacOS and RHEL, for instance, use very different top implementations.  I'll guess you are using the standard gnu/linux top that comes with "procps".  I don't see a way to do it there, unfortunately.  I took a quick glance at "atop" and "htop" and didn't see an obvious way in either of those either. A competent C programmer could probably add this pretty easily, though, especially if you kludge for a particular COMMAND. If you don't know C but know some other language, start poking around in /proc/; the standard linux top gets its info from there.

Comment: Thanks for your reply @DanPritts I edit my questions to specify the OS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How do you like this?

`watch -n 1 "ps auxw | head -n 1; ps auxw | awk '\$11 ~ /bash/ { print \$0 }' | sort -k 3 -r -n"`

Replace `bash` with the command you want to filter for.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Is not perfect cos I'm out of top command and don't have another filter and sort features live, still help me.